# Suppress checkstyle errors on PRIVATE member variables in a suppressions.xml?

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle, code-standards

On a project I am working on, checkstyle is failing with "Missing a Javadoc comment" due to a missing Javadoc comment on a **private** member variable. This seems like unnecessarily strict behaviour to me and I would like to suppress the error for private members using a suppressions XML file.

The following file succeeds in suppressing **all** checkstyle Javadoc errors on variables:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

<suppressions>
    <suppress files=".*" checks="JavadocVariable"/>
</suppressions>
```

However, this is not terribly useful behaviour because I still consider failure to document protected and public members to be an error.

How can I modify the `checks` attribute to give me the limited suppression I need?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, this cannot be achieved using suppressions, unless you want to annotate every private field. Instead, configure the [JavadocVariable](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocVariable) check so that it does not cover private scope:

```xml
<module name="JavadocVariable">
   <property name="scope" value="package"/>
</module>
```

A [scope](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/property_types.html#scope) of `package` means "`package` or more public".